# Accessing an ID tag within a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created this component within VUE:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="GISMap" v-el:map></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [GoogleMaps],

        data() {
            return {
                initialLocation: ''
            }
        },

        events: {
            MapsApiLoaded: function(data) {
                this.$set('initialLocation', this.createInitialLocation(48.184845, 11.252553));
                initGISMap(this.$el.map, this.initialLocation);
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

Now I want to pass the id `GISMap` defined in the template into my `initGISMap` function so the map can be created. But how do I pass this tag properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vue props: http://vuejs.org/api/#props

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="GISMap" :id="GISMap" v-el:map></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then inside your component:

```
props: ['id'],
```

You can access it from your methods just like you access data properties.

Ex.:

```
console.log(this.id)
```

This will output `GISMap`